# Pronunciation of “lernst”

Tags: pronunciation

It’s easy to pronounce the letter *r* in *lernen.* But when it comes to pronouncing *lernst,* it becomes really hard to keep pronouncing *r* next to *nst.*

Listening to some native speaker pronunciations ([like this](http://www.forvo.com/word/lernst/)), I realized that *r* is omitted and not pronounced in *lernst,* which makes its pronunciation much easier. Is this only a special case where *r* is omitted, or is there any general pronunciation rule which is being applied here?

Comment: When I speak *lernen* and *lernst* I pronunce the *r* in both cases identically. I think the complicated part is actually to pronounce *-nst*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The /r/ is pronounced differently by different speakers. The three most common pronunciatons for /r/ in German today are (ordered by frequency of occurrence):

- [voiced uvular fricative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_uvular_fricative) [ʁ] *(splattne's sample)*
- [uvular trill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uvular_trill) [R]
- [alveolar trill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_trill) [r]

There are other, rare and locally limited pronunciations, among them a [retroflex approximant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroflex_approximant) [ɻ] similar to the American English pronunciation. These are listed in the *Duden Grammatik*.

What you must note (and this will answer your question) is that **one speaker will pronounce all instances of /r/ in the same way**. This means that if you listen to one individual speaker, the /r/ in both "lernen" and "lernst" will sound the same.

Which pronunciation *you* choose, is up to you and depends on the variant of German you want to speak.

---

My claim that "one speaker will pronounce all instances of /r/ in the same way" is obviously wrong. All native German speakers will realize this, if they observe themselves speaking the words (1) "breit", (2) "lernst" and (3) "Lager". There is a decrease of "roll" from (1) to (3). Maybe someone wants to dig up the rules to this distribution.

Answer (score 8):

What you have here is a postvocalic r -- an r that follows a vowel. **Like in British English, postvocalic r in German isn't pronounced "properly", but it does change the vowel it follows and is itself realized as a vowel** (see also @Veri's answer).

Compare the following English word pairs for examples (and pronounce them British in your head):

> bee -- beer
>
> moo -- moor

The "ler" part of *lernen* and *lernst* rhymes with British English "fair".

---

Compare also what [Wikipedia writes about the pronunciation of R in German](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R): "Nicht überall dort, wo der Buchstabe R in der Schrift erscheint, wird er auch tatsächlich als das Phonem /r/ ausgesprochen. Meist findet sich in Wörterbüchern, die sich an die sogenannte Standardlautung des Deutschen orientieren, die Empfehlung zur Aussprache des Buchstabens als /r/ unter anderem nach den kurzen Vokalen i, ä, a, ü, ö, u, o am Wortende oder vor einem Konsonanten, z. B. [vɪr] für „wirr“ und nicht [vɪɐ̯].[1](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R) **In anderen Fällen wird meist ein abgeschwächtes a [ɐ̯] angegeben**, wie bei „Tür“, „wir“ oder „Mutter“."

Answer (score 4):

I recorded an example how to pronounce it:

https://soundcloud.com/splattne/pronunciation-of-lernst

There are two slightly different ways:

1. with a (almost) silent r
2. with an explicit r (I guess that's difficult if you're not a native speaker; also, not so common nowadays)

Answer (score 3):

I think it depends on whether you speak some special kind of dialect or not. I am from Austria, and we often pronounce the /r/-sound like an /a/-sound -> leanst. Unfortunately, I can't give you more information about this specific questions.

Comment: I do not consider myself to speak dialect (especially in this case) and I pronouonce the r in *lernst* and *lernen* identically.

Answer (score 0):

Man kann das r mehr oder weniger betonen oder rollen, aber auslassen kann man es nicht.

Auch in dem Audioschnipsel meine ich ein `r` zu hören.