# What is the symbol belonging to the IPA that represents the sound of the letter "r" in the word "rot"?

Tags: pronunciation

In the Langenscheid dictionary the word "rot" is transcribed as `[roːt]`, that is, that dictionary is saying that the symbol `[r]` express the "r" sound of the word "rot". However, using table [1] (below), it seems to me more appropriate to use the `[ʀ]` to express the "r" sound of that word. For me it becomes clearer by looking at how the `[ʀ]` (see video [2]) and `[r]` are pronounced (see video [3]).

I believe this based on the video lesson [4].

Another similar question: Which symbol belonging to the IPA best represents the "r" sound of the word "Ort"? Is `[ʀ]`, `[r]` or `[ʁ]`?

For me it's `[ʀ]` and for Langenscheid it's the `[r]`. But according to the video [5] the best symbol is the `[ʁ]`.

[1] http://web.uvic.ca/ling/resources/ipa/charts/IPAlab/IPAlab.htm

[2] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5C3TlnUoYP0

[3] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GR4zKYgROI

[4] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3C8j7y9VxUk

[5] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNn0ORQPrtA

Comment: Also related: [R's: Trilled R, Uvular Fricative R, and Uvular Trill R](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/rs-trilled-r-uvular-fricative-r-and-uvular-trill-r?noredirect=1&lq=1), [How to pronounce the German R?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20831/how-to-pronounce-the-german-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: [ʀ], [r] or [ʁ] are [allophones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allophone) in German.

Comment: And don't forget about [ɐ].