# How is "tr" pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

In my dialect of English, we pronounce *tr* like *chr* (IPA: [t͡ʃɹ]; like *tsch* if using the German spelling of the sound).

- *Tree* is pronounced *chree.*
- *Train* is pronounced *Chrain.*
- *Track* is pronounced *Chrack.*
- *Trade* is pronounced *Chrade.*

Where the *ch* beginning is similar to *choose, chop* or *chat,* but not like *Christ.* If I said *train* like how it is spelled, people would get confused because it would sound like *terrain.*

I heard my German teacher pronounce the word *tragen* in the same way so it sounds like *tschragen*. Does German pronounce *tr* that way? If not, how should I pronunce *tr* and how can I learn this pronunciation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23882/discussion-on-question-by-jwcoding-how-is-tr-pronounced).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast:  http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/906/why-cant-i-find-the-chat-room-that-was-created-from-a-comment-thread it is not **you** who needs the chat it is **us** who need it to keep comments low.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In English, *t* and *r* are both produced with the tip of the tongue, but at slightly different positions. When the tongue glides back from the *t* position to the *r* position, you get something like a *sh* /ʃ/ in between. In German, *r* is either pronounced in the back of the mouth (with the uvula) or with the tip of the tongue, but in the latter case, the tongue is not moved back from the *t* position, so there is no /ʃ/ in between.

Comment: So "tr" in German is pronounced like you would other sounds like "kr", "br" and "fr," but with a "t" sound beginning?

Comment: Would this also extend to "dr" being "jr" in English?

Comment: @jwcoding Concerning your first question: Yes, it's /t/ followed by *some r-sound*, and there are several possible r-sounds to choose (depending on the dialect), but there is never the glide effect that one gets when /t/ is followed by the English (or rather the American) /r/. Concerning your second question: I guess it's the same, at least for some English speakers (it doesn't happen with every possible English r-sound).

Comment: Maybe add a first sentence answering the question? Right now you don't answer the question, you give a justification for the answer that you merely imply (in a non-obvious way as confirmed by OPs need to ask again in the comments).

Comment: I@Nobody The question has been edited several times, in particular the question "How can I learn this pronunciation?" was added after my answer. The orginal question (whether or not a "sh" /ʃ/ is inserted between "t" and "r") is answered in my third sentence.

Answer (score 2):

You finally stated your *actual* motivation to ask this question, namely that your German teacher had pronounced a German word with the same *tr*-slurry, turning *tragen* into /tʃra:gən/.

But languages, despite being related, have completely different ways of using sounds and wildly different expectations of which sounds and which sound differences are important or not. Even languages which are really close, such as German and Dutch *do not* share many pronounciation characteristics — or frankly, pronouncing a name like *Geert* the Dutch way would not be understood in German to include a *G* out of the blue.

English and German are even less related than Dutch and German, so you can expect any pronounciation nuace present in English to be *not true* for German.

- English *t* can be realised as many things, from a glottal stop (*‘wha’?’*) over a normal *t* and, as you said, a *ch*-sound up to *sh* (*nation*).
- Japanese *t* is turned into a weak *ch* when followed by *i* and into *ts* when followed by *u*.
- I’m not even going to touch on the topic of Swedish *t*’s, which I assume to be worse than English. (Although I’m not sure which letter of *Stenstorp* is considered to create the *i*-sound in there.)
- Finnish *t* is always *t* no matter which surroundings it has.
- German is nice, because a *t* is usually a *t*, the only exception I can think of now being Latin words having a suffix starting with *-ti* (*Nation*, *Potential*)

In general, if you’re learning a language and realise your teacher is doing something that they would do with the same sounds of their native language, *assume that phenomenon not to apply to the target language until proven otherwise by native speakers!*

---

How to learn the proper pronounciation /tr/:

- [Start by trying to learn the *r*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6618/pronunciation-of-r-in-german). It’s wildly different from any of the many ways English pronounces *r*.
- Attempt to say *tr*. You’ll notice that using one of the correct ways to pronounce the German *r*, there is hardly any motivation to slurry the *tr* together into *tschr*.

Comment: I'm sorry if I offended anyone by assuming that it applied to German, but I just didn't know how to pronounce it, so I asked.

Comment: +1 for "German is nice, because a t is usually a t, the only exception I can think of now being Latin words having a suffix starting with -ti (Nation, Potential)"

Comment: No, not offending, just mainly confusing. But by leaving out the (imho) important part of your question, namely hearing it from your German teacher, all of us were like ‘so … why is he asking that?’ ;)

Comment: @Blubber Your question is totally inoffensive, while this answer is somewhat passive aggressive.