# Pronouncing bitte vs bitter

Tags: pronunciation

In [Paul Joyce's German Course](http://www.pauljoycegerman.co.uk/pronounce/vowschwa.html), he pronounces the ending of 'bitter' ([sound link)](http://www.pauljoycegerman.co.uk/pronounce/audio/bitter.wav) with a roll. This is very different from the vocalic r I've been taught, and very different from the [pronunciations on Forvo](http://www.forvo.com/word/bitter/#de).

Is this a mistake? A regional pronunciation? Or is it something else?

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6472/pronunciation-of-lernst/6482#6482

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard pronunciation for *bitter* is [ˈbɪtɐ], i.e. the phonemes /ər/ are represented by the vowel [ɐ]; for *bitte*, it is [ˈbɪtə], only differing in the final vowel, but clearly distinguishable for German native speakers.

The pronunciation [ˈbɪtər], as heard in your linked example, is very unusual, probably only used when over-enunciating. It is recommended in Theodor Siebs’s *Bühnenaussprache* (pronunciation for theater actors), which was described as “ridiculous” already a hundred years ago.

On the other hand, [ˈbɪtr] without an *ə* (or with only a very weak one) does occur in several regional variants of German, e.g. in Switzerland.